# text is cutting after click on "read more" angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 cartline">
          <div class="align-justify" hm-read-more hm-text="{{job.description}}" hm-limit="{{hm_limit/2}}" hm-more-text="{{hm_moreText}}" hm-less-text="{{hm_lessText}}" hm-dots-class="{{hm_dotsClass}}" hm-link-class="{{hm_linkClass}}">
          </div>
        </div>
```

When I click on read more I get cutting text like "should" word is "sh  ould".
Why?There is any solution? 
Thank You.

Comment: The charset is utf-8 ?

Comment: I didn't get it.Can you please explain me what happen with this code.

Comment: try to set this code in the head
`<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>`

Comment: I did this.But problem is not solved.